# Using data from text file as values for stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, automation, text-files

I've been wondering if there was a way in MySQL to read values from a text file to be used later for a stored procedure.

I am given values and I want to populate my text file with the data for `id`, `name` and `new_name`. I want my procedure to change my name to `new_name` for all the `id`'s. To automate this process I want to fill out a text file every month and have my procedure read the data and use it as values to alter the database.

If it is possible I want to purely use MySQL for this problem, avoid using temporary db tables and if stored procedures aren't possible, use another manner. Thank you in advance for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql's internal language cannot read text files. Period.

You have 2 options if you want to stick with mysql:

1. Use `load data infile` command to import the file into a temporary table. I know you said you did not want to do this, but this is the only truly native way in mysql to read sg from an external file. There is a catch, though: you cannot use load data from stored procedure for security reasons. So, you have to do at least the loading of the data outside of a stored procedure.
2. You can create user defined functions in C/C++ and add them via [create function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-function-udf.html). These functions can reach out to the file system directly. Obviously, you need to be able to implement the functionality in C/C++.

In the light of the above, I would rather create an external application that can automate this task, rather than trying to go around the restrictions in mysql.